# How to use Gutmann method SQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use the [Gutmannr method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) for a single SQL cell?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use Gutmann method for single SQL cell ?

No. A database is several layers of indirection above the actual storage while the Gutmann method relies on writes getting more or less directly passed through the hardware. Changes to data in the database will often not even overwrite data (which is a fundamental requirement of the Gutmann method) but instead write the new data on a different position and once the transaction is completed declare this new data the current one. Additionally older data remain in transaction records and backups.

Comment: Not to mention, the Gutmann method is useless for modern (non MFM) hard drives.